# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined when testing useState

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to these state methods when passing state from parent component to child component

```
const [bio, setBio] = useState("");
const [gravatar, setGravatar] = useState("");
```

but im getting this error

> ✓ Should check if EditProfile renders child component (2ms)
>       ✕ should test bio state (4ms)
>
> ● Should render  › should test bio state
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
> ```

When this test is called, What am i doing wrong ? thanks.

```
 it("should test bio state", () => {
        wrapper
            .find("EditProfileForm")
            .props()
            .handleBio();
        expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith("set bio");
    });
```

**editProfile.test.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import EditProfile from "./editProfile";
import { shallow, mount, render } from "enzyme";
import EditProfileForm from "../forms/editProfile/editForm";
import { createShallow } from "@material-ui/core/test-utils";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../store";

describe("Should render <EditProfile/>", () => {
    let wrapper;
    const setState = jest.fn();
    const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, "useState");
    useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState]);

    beforeAll(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <EditProfile />
            </Provider>,
        );
    });

    it("Should render <EditProfile/>", () => {
        expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it("Should check if EditProfile renders child component", () => {
        expect(wrapper.find("EditProfileForm")).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it("should test bio state", () => {
        wrapper
            .find("EditProfileForm")
            .props()
            .handleBio();
        expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith("set bio");
    });
});
```

**editProfile.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, Component, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import EditProfileForm from "../forms/editProfile/editForm";
import GridHoc from "../hoc/grid";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import storeMethods from "../../common/storeHooks";

function EditProfile(props: any) {
    const [bio, setBio] = useState("");
    const [gravatar, setGravatar] = useState("");
    const mounted = useRef<Object>();
    const { getProfile, profileData, userErr, message, updateProfile } = storeMethods();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!mounted.current) {
            getProfile();
            mounted.current = true;
        } else {
            setBio(bio ? bio : profileData.bio);
            setGravatar(gravatar ? gravatar : profileData.gravatar);
        }
    });
    const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = {
            bio,
            gravatar,
        };
        updateProfile(formData);
    };

    return (
        <Grid container={true} justify="center">
            <Grid item={true} xs={12} sm={12} md={8} lg={8}>
                {userErr && <Typography style={{ color: "red" }}>{message || userErr}</Typography>}
                {message && <Typography style={{ color: "green" }}>{message || userErr}</Typography>}
                <EditProfileForm handleBio={(e) => setBio(e.target.value)} handleGravatar={(e) => setGravatar(e.target.value)} onSubmit={handleSubmit} bio={bio} gravatar={gravatar} />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default GridHoc(EditProfile);
```

**editProfileForm**

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import React from "react";
const EditProfileForm = (props: any) => (
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <Typography variant="h5">Edit Profile</Typography>
        <FormGroup style={{ padding: "30px 0px" }}>
            <FormLabel style={{ display: "block" }}>Bio</FormLabel>
            <TextField
                id="outlined-name"
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                }}
                name="bio"
                multiline={true}
                rows="3"
                defaultValue={props.bio}
                onChange={props.handleBio}
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
            />
            <FormLabel style={{ display: "block" }}>Gravatar</FormLabel>
            <TextField
                id="outlined-name"
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                }}
                name="gravatar"
                multiline={true}
                rows="3"
                onChange={props.handleGravatar}
                defaultValue={props.gravatar}
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
            />
        </FormGroup>
        <Button className="subBtn" variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
        </Button>
    </form>
);

export default EditProfileForm;
```

Comment: Can you post `EditProfileForm` component code ?

Comment: @aquinq will share it now. sorry for delay

Comment: editProfileForm has its own unit test, just so you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is the way you test that `handleBio` has been called. Tests are supposed to mimic user interactions, but here you programmatically call `handleBio` which is simply useless.
Instead, you should imagine what user could possibly do with your components, and which actions must be performed then.
Here, you seem to test that `setBio` gets correctly called when `handleBio` is called, which is just testing that React binds props correctly (and you don't need / should not do that).
Instead, you need to test that `handleBio` has been called on `TextField` change and this should happen in `EditProfileForm` test.

To do so, you need to fire a change event on `TextField` (which is what would happen if user change the `TextField` value), and only after that, expect that `handleBio` has been called with the right parameters.

I suggest you use [@testing-library/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react) which will make your tests much more easier to write.

You can add a `label` attribute on both your `TextField` :

```
<TextField name="bio" label="bio" />
<TextField name="gravatar" label="gravatar" />
```

and then write the following test :

```js
// existing imports
import { render as testRender, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

const props = {
  onSubmit: jest.fn(),
  handleBio: jest.fn(),
  handleGravatar: jest.fn(),
}

const render = () => testRender(<EditProfileForm {...props} />;

describe('EditProfile', () => {

  ...

  it('calls handleBio on bio TextField change', () => {
    render();
    const input = screen.getByLabelText('bio');

    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'new value' } });

    expect(props.handleBio).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }
});
```

Comment: appreciate this, my question is... what is the difference between using  enzyme simulate change vs testing library fireEvent change ? that is my only confusion.

Comment: I'm not much familiar with enzyme itself, but I assume it's totally fine to use it as well :)

Comment: I've done more research on react testing library being that your mentioned it. It focuses on testing real actions based on the users implementation, something along those lines. Thank you for steering me in right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to only use react testing library for rendering.